Play Console Pre-launch report crash of com.google.android.gms
Since from the last update we starting having crashes related to the gms (google play services) library in the release build play console pre-launch automated tests.
We are not able to reproduce it in our test version with the emulators and the devices we have available or event in the firebase test lab (the play console uses this to do the pre-launch tests).
We already tried to bump up the firebase and google play service version and bump down to our previous versions.
The crashes are not always the same but all have the com.google.android.gms has common source for the crash. Event worse 20% of the time the pre-launch tests do not crash, during our internal testing we also tried to submit the same version only changing the versionCode and versionName and the tests crashed in the next run with the same tests being done on the same emulated device (in this case google pixel 8 android 14).
We also tried to change the proguard settings related to gms with:

-keep class com.google.android.gms.internal.** { *; }
-keep class com.google.android.gms.internal.gms.** { *; }
nothing added

The api keys were also revised and we confirm that are working correctly.
Nothing else changed inside the app besides ui and logic code inside the application not related to any library in specific.
Examples of crashes that i'm having during the tests to check if someone else is having similiar problems:
Stack trace
Native crash of com.google.android.gms
backtrace:
  #00  pc 0x000000000004f85c  /apex/com.android.runtime/lib64/bionic/libc.so (abort+168)

Exception java.lang.IllegalStateException: AppSearchBatchResult has failures: {
  successes: {}
  failures: {https://g.co/pixeltips/tips_camera_pro_controls?LaunchFrom=APP_SEARCH=[FAILURE(6)]: Schema type config 'com.google.android.apps.tips$/Tip' not found}
}
  at androidx.a.a.b.a (AppSearchBatchResult.java:1)
  at com.google.android.apps.tips.search.platform.a.d (PlatformIndex.java:11)
  at com.google.android.apps.tips.search.b.a (TipsIndexingHelper.java:20)
  at com.google.android.apps.tips.search.d.run (TipsIndexingJobService.java:1)
  at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker (ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1167)
  at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run (ThreadPoolExecutor.java:641)
  at java.lang.Thread.run (Thread.java:920)</kbd>

Stack trace
Native crash of com.google.android.gms
backtrace:
  #00  pc 0x00000000003255e4  /data/user_de/0/com.google.android.gms/app_chimera/m/00000009/CronetDynamite.uncompressed.apk

Stack trace
java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'java.lang.Class java.lang.Object.getClass()' on a null object reference
Exception java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'java.lang.Class java.lang.Object.getClass()' on a null object reference
  at android.os.Parcel.createExceptionOrNull (Parcel.java:3189)
  at android.os.Parcel.createException (Parcel.java:3167)
  at android.os.Parcel.readException (Parcel.java:3150)
  at android.database.DatabaseUtils.readExceptionFromParcel (DatabaseUtils.java:202)
  at android.database.DatabaseUtils.readExceptionFromParcel (DatabaseUtils.java:154)
  at android.content.ContentProviderProxy.call (ContentProviderNative.java:764)
  at android.content.ContentResolver.call (ContentResolver.java:2466)
  at android.content.ContentResolver.call (ContentResolver.java:2446)
  at ekfr.a (:com.google.android.gms@242013038@24.20.13 (190400-633713831):29)
  at com.google.android.gms.wallet.intentoperation.setupwizard.PaymentsSetupWizardAccountChangeIntentOperation.onHandleIntent (:com.google.android.gms@242013038@24.20.13 (190400-633713831):252)
  at com.google.android.chimera.IntentOperation.onHandleIntent (:com.google.android.gms@242013038@24.20.13 (190400-633713831):2)
  at ajdw.onHandleIntent (:com.google.android.gms@242013038@24.20.13 (190400-633713831):8)
  at pbh.run (:com.google.android.gms@242013038@24.20.13 (190400-633713831):70)
  at pbg.run (:com.google.android.gms@242013038@24.20.13 (190400-633713831):152)
  at elbx.run (:com.google.android.gms@242013038@24.20.13 (190400-633713831):21)
  at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker (ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
  at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run (ThreadPoolExecutor.java:644)
  at java.lang.Thread.run (Thread.java:1012)


Our App is implemented in android native.

I had the same issue recently. still don't know what is the cause. I'm testing on Firebase test lab and it only happens for Pixel 8 device (API 34).

Please download the log file of the Pixel 8. Especially, look if the first "PRE_ON_CREATE" of "LifecycleMonitor" is way after the reported crash. This would be a clear sign that it is not your app that causes the crash

Is your app a payed app?

We downloaded and looked into that log file, but at the time we overlooked the "PRE_ON_CREATE" of the LifecycleMonitor, thanks for the comment about that.

The app is sold as a service to businesses so it's paid but this payment is not made by the store. Meanwhile, we were able to release 2 versions of the application but still have more than 1 week delay between them. But we figured that has nothing to do with that crash and we are not the only ones with this problem ( https://x.com/astamatok/status/1810989598622847450?t=NZoYvC9Q68eu5Shtp5b8UQ&s=31 ).

@HartmutPfitzinger I'm a unity dev so I don't have much experience with Android internals. Does PRE_ON_CREATE mean the crash happens before the app/game is launched? This error is widely discussed among unity devs and many people don't have any idea if unity update did this... apparently not.

@CihadTurhan If the crash happens before the first PRE_ON_CREATE then it is not the app that crashes, but something that the phone prepares prior to launching the app for the first time. The is the case with my app, and I suspect some misconfiguration of that specific phone

@PedroMoura maybe the payment causes some action which might be misconfigured in that specific phone.

It ended up being a problem related to our privacy policy this was only a coincidence at the wrong time. But we interpreted it as the problem, meanwhile we were able to release the application and didn't detect any extra crashes related to this in production. So for now we are not actively trying to solve it.
